# How to present this group derived from sliding tile puzzles?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

While researching [sliding tile puzzles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliding_puzzle), I tried to extend their groupoid structure to a proper group, yielding the following group:

The group $G$ represents permutations of the points of the square lattice. Let the object on the square lattice at coordinates $i,j$ be known as $e_{i,j}$. The group has two generators $r$ and $u$ that permute objects on the square lattice like this: $r(0,0) = e_{0,0}$, $r(1,0) = e_{-1,0}$ and for all other $(i,j)$, it is $r(i,j)=e_{i-1,j}$. Similarly, $u(0,0) = e_{0,0}, u(0,1)=e_{0,-1}$ and for all other $(i,j)$, it is $u(i,j)=e_{i,j-1}.$ For convenience, let $l\colon=r^{-1}$ and $d\colon=u^{-1}$. Intuitively, one can think of the lattice as an infinite sliding tile puzzle with $u,d,l,r$ moving a tile up, down, left, or right into the free spot.

If this group has been researched before, what is it called? How can I present this group? Is there an easy way to find all relators of a certain length?